# How can I remove "ImageMagick" completely?

Tags: linux, unix, centos, imagemagick

I think I accidently did install 2 ImageMagicks to my CentOS 5.8 before.

Version 6.2.8 was removed by

```
yum erase ImageMagick
```

However, it still shows this when I typed `$convert -version`

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.8.2-9 2013-02-11 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2013 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: DPC OpenMP
Delegates: jng jpeg png ps xml zlib
```

`which convert` shows this

```
/usr/local/bin/convert
```

This one. I probably installed from the source.
How can I remove this?

Comment: What does 'rpm -qf /usr/local/bin/convert' show?

Comment: @Justin Thanks it showed `file /usr/local/bin/convert is not owned by any package`

Comment: I might have installed it by wget and make => make install

Comment: Just downloaded the ImageMagick source, and you're lucky! it comes with an uninstall target. just run 'make uninstall' from your build folder and it will remove it. This is not common and is the reason to prefer building/using packages over building from source; .

Comment: @Justin Thanks for reply. what folder shoud I go? cd /usr/local/bin/convert  and execute make uninstall?

Comment: Wherever you downloaded the source and originally ran './configure && make && make install'. Or just download it again and run './configure && make uninstall'.

Comment: @Justin   The problem is that I cannot find where the folder is. and I don't know where I downloaded that file from:(

Comment: Try http://www.imagemagick.org/download/ImageMagick.tar.gz It's the one from their site that I downloaded. It's 6.8.2.10 instead of 6.8.2-9, but it should do the trick.

Comment: what should I do? 1. wget http://www.imagemagick.org/download/ImageMagick.tar.gz 2.???

Comment: yep, 'wget http://www.imagemagick.org/download/ImageMagick.tar.gz' 'tar zxvf ImageMagick.tar.gz' 'cd ImageMagick-6.8.2-10' './configure' 'make uninstall'

Comment: Thanks:) please put that in answer so that I can vote it up

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Run 'make uninstall' from the ImageMagick source folder, it includes an uninstall target.

> wget imagemagick.org/download/ImageMagick.tar.gz
>   tar zxvf ImageMagick.tar.gz
>   cd ImageMagick-6.8.2-10
>   ./configure
>   make uninstall